# PHP cut specifc piece of data from string

Tags: php, string

I have the following String that contains some unwanted substring that should be trimmed out.

```
<?php
$str = "
    23' CHE[1-1]SOU\n
    19:00 EVE-NEW\n
    19:00 MUN-TOT\n
    4' [4-4]\n
    1' [1-1]\n
    \n
    important info";
?>
```

I want to get rid of this sub-string from above string

```
4' [4-4]\n
1' [1-1]\n
\n
```

How do i get rid of it without deleting the information above and below it.

Comment: how come we identify the above?

Comment: Which pattern does this follow ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question so far this will work:

```
$newstr = preg_replace("/^.*(4.*1-1\]\n\n).*/", "$1", $str);
```

as will this:

```
$newstr = substr($str, 45, 19);
```

as will this:

```
$newstr = "4' [4-4]\n1' [1-1]\n\n";
```